# Why are there no hierarchies based on time?

Tags: ssas

Why is it not necessary to define a hierarchy using the Date attribute from a date/time table?

The Analysis Service project seems to want me to create a hierarchy within my Dimension -- the tooltip says "Create hierarchies in non-parent child dimensions".  I really had none that came to mind, so I tried adding a the PK Date attribute from my Time table, and creating a hierarchy with that.

When I do this, I get the error "Errors in the high-level relational engine. The 'dbo_Orders' table that is required for a join cannot be reached based on the relationships in the data source view."

I noticed in the AdventureWorks sample never uses Date in a hierarchy.  Why is this?